# Design Patterns - One public class utilizing many hidden classes

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

I have gone through http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns in trying to find out the most efficient to create a design pattern in which "one visible class utilizes many hidden classes" to create a fluent API.  Below is the code I currently have:

```
public class VisibleClass {
    Private OrderClass order;
    private ReceiptClass receipt;

    public VisibleClass makeOrder() {
        if (!(order instanceof OrderClass))
            order = new OrderClass();

        order.make();
        return this;
    }

    public VisibleClass printReceipt() {
        if (!(receipt instanceof ReceiptClass))
            receipt = new ReceiptClass();

        receipt.print();
        return this;
    }
}

class OrderClass implements IOrder {
    public void make() {}
}

class ReceiptClass implements IReceipt {
    public void print() {}
}

interface IOrder { void make(); }
interface IReceipt { void print(); }
```

Here is how I am currently using the API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VisibleClass x = new VisibleClass();
    x.makeOrder().printReceipt();
}
```

It this a good approach?  Can a better approach be used for it?

*EDIT:  Also, I should add that the VisibleClass will implement all methods of the hidden classes.

Comment: You may wish to consider posting this at [codereview.se] for reviewing working code. Be sure to read their help section for [topics you can ask about](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you Mike. I wasn't aware of this branch of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one visible class utilizes many hidden classes

don't do that with business classes. Fluent syntax's is great for configuration etc, but not for plain business code.

The reason is that the class itself losses control over it's state which can put it in an inconsistent state (i.e generate faulty results).

There is even a principle called [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which is about just that.

If you have a business requirement that a receipt should be printed on a new order you should just return it as a return value.

`var receipt = visibleClass.makeOrder();`

As for using interfaces for entity/business classes, why do you do that? why would you want to abstract away those? The usually do not have any other dependencies or different types of implementations.

Comment: Thank you jgauffin.  The example shows business classes but these are not business classes in reality, it was just an example.  The requirement is to create a fluent API around those, do you think the above will be a good approach knowing they aren't business classes?

Comment: I don't see the point of the interfaces? Other than that it looks OK for a fluent syntax.

Comment: The interfaces should go away, yes.  I had added them for visibility's sake for the calling code because I was using a different approach earlier but this seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quite good. Here some recommendations:

1 Change class member types to their interfaces as for 'Program to an interface, not an implementation' principle:

```
public class VisibleClass {
    private IOrder order;
    private IReceipt receipt;
```

2 Do you really need to check class types in `makeOrder` and `printReceipt` methods ? Creating instances after `null` check seems enough:

```
public VisibleClass makeOrder() {
    if (null == order)
        order = new OrderClass();

    order.make();
    return this;
}

public VisibleClass printReceipt() {
    if (null == receipt)
        receipt = new ReceiptClass();

    receipt.print();
    return this;
}
```

3 This approach is valid until methods of `VisibleClass` will be called by a single thread. If you're going to place it in a multi-thread program, you should ensure that there are only one instances of `OrderClass` and `ReceiptClass` each. There are 3 ways you can follow:

a. Create instaces of `OrderClass` and `ReceiptClass` in constructor and make `VisibleClass` singleton.

b. Make `OrderClass` and `ReceiptClass` singleton and remove `new` lines.

c. Create instances surrounded with `synchronized` block in `makeOrder` and `printReceipt` methods.

Comment: Thank you Efe.  This is a single threaded program that writes to a single text file, but I like to idea of making the private classes singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Facade Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Or may be try using a [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)